# using map with nested data frame and varying min max values for different factor levels

Tags: r, dictionary

Example dataset

```
dummy<-data.frame(CommonName=c("American Plaice","Skate","Scallop",
                               "Yellowtail","Skate",
                               "American Plaice","Skate",
                               "Skate","Scallop","Yellowtail"),
                               StationID=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
                               Gear=c("Com","Exp","Exp","Com","Exp","Com","Com","Exp","Exp","Com"),
                               Length=c(104,200,65,100,95,100,1400,1000,75,90),
                               number=c(1,2,3,1,3,2,1,1,2,1))

dummy$CommonName<-as.factor(dummy$CommonName)
dummy$StationID<-as.factor(dummy$StationID)
dummy$Gear<-as.factor(dummy$Gear)
```

packages required

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
```

I would like to have length data with a 0 for number for all StationID, CommonName and Gear. For the nested length data I would like to only have length values for the range (min,max) of length data for each species.

The orginial example dataset looks like this:

[image]

The end dataset would look like this:

[image]

One attempt was:

```
  smpv1.length.data1<-dummy %>%
      group_by(StationID)%>%
      expand(CommonName, Gear, Length)
```

All StationID,CommonName, Gear have the same length ranges

Second attempt:

```
smpv1.length.data1 <- dummy %>%
  group_by(StationID) %>%                
  nest(CommonName,Gear) %>%  # nest data and use expand.grid
  mutate(data = purrr::map(data, ~ expand.grid(seq(min(.x$Length),max(.x$Length),1,),
                                               mean(.x$number)))) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%  # unnest data
  setNames(c("StationID","CommonName","Gear","Length","number"))
```

I get error messages:

```
 Error in seq.default(min(.x$Length), max(.x$Length), 1, ) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
 Unknown or uninitialised column: `Length`. 
3: In min(.x$Length) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Length`. 
5: In max(.x$Length) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Third attempt

```
smpv1.length.data1<-dummy %>%  complete(nesting(StationID),
                    nesting(CommonName,Gear),
                    Length,fill=list(number=0)) %>%
                    as.data.frame()
```

All StationID,CommonName, Gear have the same length ranges

R session info:
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the logic of your desired result is not clear to me, i.e. could you clarify why only for `CommonName = "American Plaice"` and `StationID==1` the `Length` gets expanded and also, why it gets expanded to 100:104?